# A limit in two variables with absolute value

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to calculate (if it exists) the following limit: $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{\ln(1+|xy|)}{x^{2}+y^{2}}.$$ What I did is simply to consider that $\ln(1+\theta)\sim\theta$ as $\theta\rightarrow 0$. So I have the limit: $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{|xy|}{x^{2}+y^{2}}.$$ I know the inequality: $$|x|+|y|\ge \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$ which I used in the previous exercises, but here there is a product of absolute values and not a sum, so I think it is not useful. How should I proceed?

Comment: You might use $2xy\le x^2+y^2$? This would give you an upper bound of $\frac 12$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your limit is a quotient of polynomials, you should look at the degrees. Here both numerator and denominator have the same degree $2$, which for a several-variable limit suggests it doesn't exist.

Now you can try $x=0$, where the limit is $0$, and $x=y$, where the limit is $1/2$.